# Database test faillure with dbUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, dbunit, php-5.4

I'm trying to execute some databasetests with php unit but I keep getting the following errors:
[image: following errors:]

My composer.json look like this:

```
{
    "require": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8",
    "phpunit/dbunit": "^2.0"
}
```

This is the page I'm trying to perform the test on:

```
<?php 
require_once 'autoload.php';

class testDatabase extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase {


public function getConnection() {
    $db = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mrf", 
        "", "");
    return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($db, "bulletproof");
}

}
?>
```

I use the sql autoloader to load the main php classes and that looks like the following:

```
<?php 
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once '../classes/' . $class . '.php';
});
?>
```

In my opinion, the strange thing is that the regular phpunit tests do run, but the dbUnit test do not. I tried several upgrades of composer, phpUnit and dbUnit downloaded from packagist but without succes.

Would be great if you could help me out,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `composer install`, composer generates file `PROJECT_ROOT/vendor/autoload.php`. That file contains all stuff needed for autoloading your project dependencies, so based on what I see on the screenshot, you need to `require_once` it as well as your own.

---

As a side note: phpunit has an option `--bootstrap=filename`, which is executed before all tests run. You can run

```
phpunit --bootstrap=PROJECT_ROOT/vendor/autoload.php databaseTest.php
```

After that you can create something like phpunit_bootstrap.php, put your `require_once 'autoload.php';` here and composers vendor/autoload.php so you can run tests like

```
phpunit --bootstrap=path/to/your/phpunit_bootstrap.php AnythingYouWantToTest.php
```

without need to insert `require_once 'autoload.php';` in every test file.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your answer. When I do like you say and require the `vendor/autoload.php` I get the following Error: `Argument #3 of <no value> of phpunit_textUI_resultprinter::construct--() must be a value from  "never", "auto" or "always"` I searched this error and moved phpunit from `require-dev` to `dev`. Unfortunately no result. I run phpunit 5.3.2 right now. You have any idea's? Thanks!

Comment: Do you run `vendor/bin/phpunit` or your system-wide installed version? Unfortunately no ideas from the first view except guesses. Maybe it deserves another question on this site

Comment: yes it is. Hmm to bad... I really liked the idea of testdriven development but untill not it has been a pain to get it to work :P Thanks for your help and I will open another question.